# Using Emmet with SCSS

Tags: sass, sublimetext2, emmet

I've just started using SASS with Sublime Text 2 and it's great. I'm using the SCSS syntax.

However, I've been using Emmet and it does not seem to work with SCSS well when using tab (for me). With Emmet, I usually write: `float` and press tab, it converts it to `float;`. This is only after I made the following change to the preferences, for SCSS:

```
{
    "preferences": {
        "sass.propertyEnd": ";"
    }
}
```

However, I also commonly write a class or element name: `body`, press tab and it creates `body { }`, with the cursor within the brackets. This seems to have stopped working, and since I've changed the preferences, it just ends the property with `;.

Is there a way to get this autocomplete function back, with element names and attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you wanted to set `propertyEnd` initially, but I can highly recommend the even shorter expansions Emmet has to offer:

Ex: Type `fl` followed by <kbd>tab</kbd> and you should get `float: left;` with the 'left' already highlighted for you to change. `fr` also expands to `float: right;`.

I'm not sure if these are standard with Emmet or if they come with the SCSS Package for Sublime, but they save me a lot of time. If you get used to them it's even quicker then typing out a full `float` before hitting tab.

Comment: I think what his saying is that Emmet doesn't work as it should with SCSS. I'm having the same problem and still no luck.